# Run a web page with 3000 user requests, hw requirements

Tags: apache, joomla, load, hardware

My team and I have build a site on Joomla (php,apache,mysql) , basically a publishing article site with no user interaction, and some JS modules.
The site is famous and at some peak times there are 2500-3500 requests accessing it, the site get very slow and look very bad on user experience. The upload target is not the issue.

I need some suggestions on HW requirements and technologies I can use like apache enhance, php modules or any proxy infrastructure.

Does anyone done a study ore an analyse on this topics, I can't find anything util searching on web and I'm all ears to hear any suggestion.

Thank you

Comment: Am I correct in assuming you're on a shared hosting package?

Comment: Hello,thanks for answering, actually the site was on a shared server during maintenance, but the production now is on a physical server. Ironically the copy on the shared server works great, including that doesn't have the traffic load.

Comment: This question is about Joomla management, you may get a better result if you, try asking on [the Joomla Q&A StackExhange site](http://joomla.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but more than a joomla problem I see it as HW and web-server problem. I am more concerned on HW, Apache and PHP because I can manage the joomla part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We currently manage a few sites that are more or less similar. Here's the hardware from one of them:

- 16 GB RAM
- 500 GB Hard Disk (not SSD)
- 8 core processor

Note, however, that for high traffic websites we do modify the Joomla core, and we also switch the tables from InnoDB to MyISAM (regardless what others might think here, MyISAM is much faster than InnoDB ). We only use first level caching (we rarely use the "System - Cache" plugin).

Comment: Hello,thanks for writing
I will try switching the SQL tables. Haven't you try any apache changes or use of a proxy server before your apache, wikipedia claims that has a 80% better performance only by using squid proxy.